# mplfinance : i dont want it to show date

Tags: python, datetime, mplfinance

I want that the figure does not show the date on a specific subplot

I did find nothing on internet including stackoverflow, and the doc of mplfinance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf
import datetime as dt


fig= mpf.figure(style="yahoo",figsize=(12,8))



 axlist=[ fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)]
 axlist.append(fig.add_subplot(2,1,2,sharex=axlist[0] ))

df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', index_col=0,parse_dates=True)

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", returnfig=True, ax=axlist[0], volume = axlist[1])
mpf.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mplfinance already does this for you *if you let it*.

In order to do this (for the type of plot that you are making, and in fact for most plots) ***do not use external axes***.  When you do use external axes, you prevent mplfinance from doing these types of things for you (and you end up having to write a lot more code to do it yourself).

You should read carefully through [**the mplfinance tutorial on "panels"**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb) to see exactly how to do what you are trying to accomplish (i.e. with no axes labels in between the panels).

Essentially your code should look like this:

```py
# DELETE THIS LINE: fig= mpf.figure(style="yahoo",figsize=(12,8))
# DELETE THIS LINE: axlist=[ fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)]
# DELETE THIS LINE: axlist.append(fig.add_subplot(2,1,2,sharex=axlist[0] ))

df = pd.read_csv('df.txt', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

mpf.plot(df, type="candle", style='yahoo', volume=True, panel_ratios=(1,1))

mpf.show()
```

**NOTICE** that I have added the kwarg `panel_ratios=(1,1)`.  This is because in your plot you made the candlestick panel and the volume panel the same size, and I am assuming you wanted it that way on purpose.  Notice also that there is no need for `returnfig=True`.

---

If you still insist on using external axes (*which I strongly do **not*** recommmend) then you can remove the x-axis labels with `axlist[0].xaxis.set_tick_params(labelbottom=False)`.